# elasticsearch queue size for search threadpool

Tags: elasticsearch, threadpool

I have one transport client instance for the whole application. I am able to process 8 parallel searches to elasticsearch.

But when I try to perform 10 or more parallel search request I am getting esRejected execution exception.

Do I have to increase the queue size of the search thread pool. Can i do it from client side or server settings in elasticsearch.yml

Thanks.

Comment: you need give detail, such as search commands, real error log, or screenshot, elasticsearch.yml content, etc.

Comment: normal search query only. and the default queue size for search thread pool is 1000.

Comment: {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "match" : {
        "CityName" : {
          "query" : "Chennai",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Is not recommended to increase the queue size or the thread pool default configuration, as your cluster could become unstable. Add more nodes to increase the compute power or, if not possible, this would be the concurrent search limit of your cluster and you need to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the error you're talking about is the following one:

> org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor

I got the exact same problem few days back. The use case for me was 16 concurrent requests to elasticsearch where each request is a bulk insert.Before i start with what i did, i'd like to explain what is causing this error.When you fire bulk requests to elasticsearch servers,they are processed via thread pools(default value=8). The remaining messages are appended in the queue if there are no ideal threads left. This queue gets filled up if there are too many simultaneous requests made to elasticsearch.
Following are the different solutions i tried:

1. In the helpers.bulk call you can pass the chunk_size which defaults to 500. chunk size is internal to elasticsearch which divides your data into batches and then passes the request further. So greater is the chunk size, lesser number of messages are appended in the queue and vice versa. The only drawback to this solution is that as the chunk size grows, you are close to hitting the max_chunk_bytes value (default 100Mb) which means that the chunk size you're sending shouldn't be greater than this limit. For me, each record had a size of 2.1kb and thus i was comfortable with giving a chunk size of 40k.
2. Increasing the queue size: You can increase the queue size under ThreadPool.bulk.queue_size, the default value being 50. Increasing queue size means you put more memory load on the elasticsearch servers which is actually dependent on your machine size. The machine size i was using had 61Gb of memory. I stress tested the servers with max load by having 105 parallel requests and a chunk size of 1000.
3. Limit the concurrency: If you're able to handle the requests at the client size then you don't put lot of message requests in the queue and the base problem is solved.

The above operation can be carried out by calling the es api:

```
 helpers.bulk(es_client, query, request_timeout=200, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
```

The parameters like request_timeout & chunk_size are passed onto kwargs of helpers.bulk which in turn calls streaming_bulk.

See the thread pool configurations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

Detailed description of helpers method [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers)